# Java - Authorize an application for GitHub

Tags: java, api, github, token, authorize

I'm developing a Java application which uses GitHub API to download Zips of users' repositories, but every time I execute it, it exceeds the rate limit . How can I authorize my Java application to reach 5000 requests per hour?

- I don't want to use other libraries, just pure GitHub API
- I have a token I can use to authorize

Answer (score 0):

from https://developer.github.com/v3/

> Increasing the unauthenticated rate limit for OAuth applications
>
> If your OAuth application needs to make unauthenticated calls with a
>   higher rate limit, you can pass your app's client ID and secret as
>   part of the query string.
>
> curl -i
>   'https://api.github.com/users/whatever?client_id=xxxx&client_secret=yyyy'

Comment: But it also states: This method should only be used for server-to-server calls. You should never share your client secret with anyone or include it in client-side browser code

Comment: I am assuming that your Java application is a server side application

Comment: I forgot to say that, sorry. No, I am writing a simple java program which executes from desktop, I just need to authorize it for GitHub (using a token I already have). Do I have to include some specific parameter in each API call (http get), or is there another way?

Comment: If the jar is to be run by you (only) then it fits the server-to-server call scenario. But in case you are sharing the jar, I would also recommend to let the user pass his OAuth as a parameter or debug option which running the jar. Otherwise I am assuming if multiple people use the jar with same OAuth the TPS will get distributed.

Comment: Oh, I never thought of that. Ok, so I can treat my app as a server-to-server application, now how can I do the authorization work?
I have 2 types of request in my code:
 1) retrieve a json from a url (based on the api call I want to make) without any http get
 2)  http get for downloading the actual zip (URLConnection).
So, I could add at any urls I use (both for the http get and the json request) "?acces_token=TOKEN" at the end or something like that, or is there  another better way?

Comment: I would do that. You might try this http://github.jcabi.com/index.html. I just found it over internet

Comment: Yes, finally I did as I said and it works (I mean the rate limit), also I have already tried that library, but I have not been able to find something to download the zip and using pure api is easier in my opinion. So I can't use that library for the authorization process and then pure api for the rest, can I?

Comment: It should be possible. Their doc says - Entire Github API is available, at least through a configurable HTTP request. Did you try repo content or releases.

Answer (score 0):

from https://developer.github.com/v3/ there are two ways once you have OAUTH token

> 1. OAuth2 Token (sent in a header)
>
> curl -H "Authorization: token OAUTH-TOKEN" https://api.github.com
>   OAuth2 Token (sent as a parameter)
>
> 2. curl https://api.github.com/?access_token=OAUTH-TOKEN

e.g. curl https://api.github.com/rate_limit?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxx

Getting OAUTH (access) token Refer - https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/#create-a-new-authorization

Approach 1

Using your user id and password (as used to login on the web)

curl -X POST https://api.github.com/authorizations -d '{ "scopes": ["public_repo"],"note": "admin script"}' -u :

Approach 2

Using your application's client id and secret

curl -X POST https://api.github.com/authorizations -d '{ "scopes": ["public_repo"],"note": "admin script", "client_id": "", "client_secret": ""}'

Approach 3

curl -X PUT https://api.github.com/authorizations/clients/ -d '{ "scopes": ["public_repo"],"note": "admin script", "client_secret": ""}'

In the response of the any of the above calls you would get a value
"token": "abcdefgh12345678",

This is the OAUTH or access token. Keep a copy of this token.

You should be able to generate the token using the web as well https://github.com/blog/1509-personal-api-tokens

Since we have acquired this token with access to only the public repo, it should be safe to use it for gain in TPS.